# Try to connect to Mosquitto MQTT over WebSockets with Mqtt.js

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I want to build a web page to send and receive topics. I'm using [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/) and [MQTT.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js).

1. I'm using this as an config file:

   ```
   protocol websockets
   listener 1884
   ```
2. I run `sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` and get

   ```
   1647529861: mosquitto version 2.0.14 starting
   1647529861: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
   1647529861: Opening websockets listen socket on port 1884.
   1647529861: mosquitto version 2.0.14 running
   ```
3. I'm using a simple `mqtt.html` ([full source](https://pastebin.com/qJLzW6KG)):

   ```
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   const client = mqtt.connect("ws://localhost:1884")
   </script>
   ```

Problem:

- In Chrome it just connects with 101 and does it again and again. When you check the websockets messages, the "server" receives: `00000000: 2002 0005`. When I check the log of mosquitto: I get a lot of `1647530429: Client mqttjs_b0e54ea4 closed its connection.`

I'm running on:

```
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: ManjaroLinux
Description:    Manjaro Linux
Release:    21.2.5
Codename:   Qonos
```

Comment: You need to include the full code in the question, the important bit is missing and it's not that long. Also that pastebin link will eventually expire making it useless

Comment: Also is that your full mosquitto.conf because what you've posted should not give that log output. You need to have the `protocol` after the `listener` for it to take effect as intended.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `allow_annonymous true` to your config file.

The default for mosquitto 2.x is to not allow connections from unauthenticated clients.

You should also reverse the lines in your config,

The `protocol` option only applies to the last `listener` in order down the file.

What you have will apply the websocket protocol to the default listener on port 1883.

```
allow_anonymous true
listener 1884
protocol websockets
```